# Assigning <E> to String

Tags: java, linked-list, tostring

Hi everytime I tried to compile this, I always get an error saying I cannot assign E to String. Please help me with this. Thank you

```
public String toString() {
     ListNode<E> start = head;
      String result = "";
      if (numNodes == 1) {
          result = start.getElement();
      }
      else {
          for (int i = 0; i<numNodes-2; i++) {
              result = result + start.getElement();
              start = start.getNext();
          }
      result = result + start.getElement();
      }
  }
```

Comment: What do you think `result = start.getElement()` should do? Why do you think so?

Comment: start.getElement() suppose to return the element inside the listNode which is <E> and I want to assign E to result

Comment: Use `ListNode<String>` not `E`.

Comment: when you create a `StringNode<E>` the `data` it will store will be of type `E` so when you do a `getElement()` it gets the element of type `E` not `String`

Comment: E is type parameter; and it seems that you have no understanding of generic types. You might want to study some documentation (for example https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/ ) before using something you don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use String.valueOf(Val) to convert an object to string